# Has anyone seen Swagger throw an exception because it can't find ClassGraph?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm using 2.1.16 of Swagger with Jetty/Jersey and I get this exception. I have tried to turn off classpath scanning with readAllResources(false) on SwaggerConfiguration because I don't want this feature anyway but it didn't help. I'm probably doing something wrong here. But what?

Thanks,
Jonathan

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph
    at io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2@2.1.6/io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.JaxrsAnnotationScanner.classes(JaxrsAnnotationScanner.java:60)
    at io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2@2.1.6/io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.JaxrsApplicationAndAnnotationScanner.classes(JaxrsApplicationAndAnnotationScanner.java:10)
    at io.swagger.v3.oas.integration@2.1.6/io.swagger.v3.oas.integration.GenericOpenApiContext.read(GenericOpenApiContext.java:555)
    at io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2@2.1.6/io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.OpenApiServlet.doGet(OpenApiServlet.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.api@3.1.0/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.api@3.1.0/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at wicket.core@9.2.0/org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:293)
    at wicket.core@9.2.0/org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:208)
    at wicket.core@9.2.0/org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@9.4.36.v20210114/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swagger includes an outdated version of the io.github.classgraph that causes the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I was able to exclude the classgraph version that was being included by Swagger and include the most recent version. After that I was missing the requires statement in module-info.java and now it works. This issue has been fixed in master of Swagger repo, but it is not yet in any release.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Tomer Swagger includes an outdated version of the io.github.classgraph that causes the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I was able to exclude the classgraph version that was being included by Swagger and include the most recent version. After that I was missing the requires statement in module-info.java and now it works. This issue has been fixed in master of Swagger repo, but it is not yet in any release.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this with the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The only thing that worked for me was to downgrade to 1.6.3 and it got rid of the `Cannot resolve io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.13`8 error.